# WPF loading jpg image by code error - BitmapMetadata is not available on BitmapImage

Tags: wpf, image, c#-4.0

Very frustrated with this.

I'm having an issue loading jpg images only via code. Same images are loaded correctly if I load them in XAML.
e.g:

```
<Image Source="Assets/Images/Backgrounds/ChangeSelectionImg.jpg" />
```

But this code doesn't load the same image, but works fine with PNG images:

```
var uriSource = new Uri(@"C:\Work\TestApp\Assets\Images\Backgrounds\ChangeSelectionImg.jpg", UriKind.Absolute);

var bmi = new BitmapImage();
bmi.BeginInit();
bmi.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
bmi.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.IgnoreImageCache;
bmi.UriSource = uriSource;
bmi.EndInit();
var image = new Image
{
    Width = 187,
    Height = 700,
    StretchDirection = StretchDirection.DownOnly,
    Stretch = Stretch.Fill,
    Source = bmi
};

SpImage.Children.Add(image);
```

I haven't tried with Relative URI because the actual image I want to load is a folder external to the application. The image path will be specified in the database.

Even tried the `BitmapCreateOptions.IgnoreColorProfile` option as suggested [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/DealingWithImagesWithBadMetadataCorruptedColorProfilesInWPF.aspx), but that didn't work either.

The code below works with PNG images but not jpg:

```
var imagePath = "some absolute path to an image";
var uriSource = new Uri(imagePath, UriKind.Absolute);

var image = new Image
{
    Width = 187,
    Height = 700,
    StretchDirection = StretchDirection.DownOnly,
    Stretch = Stretch.Fill,
    Source = new BitmapImage(uriSource)
};
```

I'm at a loss of ideas now. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Since I couldn't figure out why this was happening and no one helping :(
Just in case someone else gets stuck in the same way, this is what I decided to do:

```
var bannerImg = new ImageBrush(new BitmapImage(uriSource))
{
    Stretch = Stretch.Uniform
};

SpImage.Background = bannerImg;
```

I set the background image of the StackPanel to the image.

I'm still open to suggestions.

Answer (score -1):

BitMapImage doesn't support BitMapMetaData, It throws System.NotSupported exception, using JpegBitmapDecoder will resolve this issue.